# Ignore collision in specific circumstances while still using it as a trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, collision

I am making a 2D platformer type of game. In this platformer there are both the player and "enemies". The problem arises because: I need both enemies and players to collide with the ground so they don't fall through it. I need to detect when a player collides with an enemy so i can register damage. I need the player to be able to walk through an enemy. Having colliders on the feet is not an option because the player may interact with it. What is the best way to approach this kind of specific collision detection?

Comment: you can use `LayerMask` and boolean on it to define specific Collision with or you can add `compare tag("YourTag")` can you add more details ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Layer Collision Matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LayerBasedCollision.html) (Edit -> ProjectSettings -> Physics2D) to define exactly which [layers](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Layers.html) can collide with which other layers.

So I would simply use two colliders on the player:

- one is **not** a trigger so it can collide with the ground. Put this on a layer `playerGround` which collides with the `ground` layer.
- the other one **is** a trigger and can collide with the enemy layer. Name it e.g. `playerEnemy` or something.

Since each GameObject can only have one layer your colliders would have to sit on different objects e.g. like

```
player (Rigidbody2D)
|--GroundCollider(layer: playerGround)
|--EnemyCollider(layer:playerEnemy, isTrigger)
```

The `enemy` layer can collide with both the `ground` and the `playerEnemy`.

This way both can walk on the ground. Player can walk through enemies but you can use `OnTriggerEnter` to detect the collisions with enemies.